# Fulton Ex. 3.2.22: Counting conics intersecting 8 lines in 3-space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I'm trying to understand Fulton's approach to the question how many plane conics in $\mathbb P^3$ meet 8 general lines. Suppose $V$ is a 4-dimensional vector space, and $\mathbb P^3 = \mathbb P(V)$. Then the Grassmannian $G = G(V, 3)$ parametrizes planes in $\mathbb P(V)$, and comes with a canonical sequence of locally free sheaves
$$ 0 \to \mathbb A \to V \otimes \mathcal O_G \to \mathbb B \to 0,$$
with $\operatorname{rk}(\mathbb A) = 1$ and $\operatorname{rk}(\mathbb B) = 3$. Plane conics are parametrized by the $\mathbb P^5$-bundle $\mathbb P(\operatorname{Sym}^2\mathbb B^\vee) \to G$. Suppose $l \subset \mathbb P(V)$ is a line which corresponds to a 2-dimensional quotient $V \to W$. Then the planes which contain $l$ form a dual line $l^\vee \subset G$, and on $U = G \setminus l^\vee$ one has the two short exact sequences
\begin{equation}\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
0 @>>>\mathbb A|_U @>>> V \otimes \mathcal O_U @>>> \mathbb B|_U @>>> 0 \\
{}@VVV @VVV @VVV\\
0 @>>>\mathbb A|_U @>>> W \otimes \mathcal O_U @>>> \mathcal L @>>> 0 \\
\end{CD}\end{equation}
for some line bundle $\mathcal L$ on $U$. Taking second symmetric power of the surjection $\mathbb B|_U \to \mathcal L$ and combining this with the canonical quotient $\pi^* \operatorname{Sym}^2 \mathbb B^* \to \mathcal O_{\pi}(1)$ one obtains a global section
$$ s \in \Gamma(\pi^{-1} U, \pi^* \operatorname{Sym}^2 \mathcal L \otimes \mathcal O_{\pi}(1)).$$
By construction this section vanishes exactly at those conics which meet $l$.

Fulton claims that $\mathcal L = \mathbb A|_U$. Here is what I tried:

> We have $G \cong \mathbb P^3$, and with this identification $\mathbb A = \mathcal O(1)$, and so $\operatorname{Pic}(G) = \mathbb  Z \cdot \mathbb A$. Also $\operatorname{Pic}(G) \cong A_3(G)$, since $G$ is smooth, and looking at the exact sequence
> $$ 0 = A_3(l^\vee) \to A_3(G) \to A_3(U) \to 0$$
> we see that $\mathcal L = \mathcal O(k)|_U$ for some uniquely determined $k$.
>
> But why is $k=1$?
> I think if $k > 0$ then any $\mathcal O(k)$  is generated by $x_0^k$ and $x_1^k$ outside the line $\{x_0 = x_1 = 0\}$, so the fact that $\mathcal L$ is generated by two elements is not sufficient.

Comment: Do you know of section "9.7 Conics in ${\Bbb P}^3$ meeting eight lines" in "3264 & All That" by Eisenbud and Harris?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I haven't read this in detail, and their approach seems to differ from Fulton (or Fulton is really brief). For example it looks like they use the full description of $A(\mathbb P(S^2 \mathbb B^*))$, which Fulton only explains in chapter 3.3.

Comment: Also just in case you're interested in how to get the number in [Schubert2](https://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/usr/share/doc/Macaulay2/Schubert2/html/___Example_spfrom_sp__Schubert_co_sp__Count_spthe_spnumber_spof_spspace_spconics_spintersecting_sp8_spgiven_splines.html) or [schubert](https://github.com/jmokland/schubert/blob/master/schubertlib/schubert/src/examples) (see lines 53-55).